# Problem with installing Realtek rtl8188eus driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 WiFi adapter in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wifi, drivers, directory

I'm new to linux. I'm using Linux Lite 5.2 OS (Ubuntu 20.04). While trying to install a Realtek driver for a TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 WiFi adapter using `git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus` , it's giving this error message:

```
cut: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC [M]  /home/user/rtl8188eus/8188eu.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/rtl8188eus/8188eu.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-89-generic'
cut: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.4.0-89-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 5.4.0-89-generic
```

I ran the code with sudo but still got this error. I tried to create redhat-release directory myself with `mkdir` in /etc/ and made it writable with `chmod +rwx` and giving permissions with `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/redhat-release` but it shows this error message:

```
cut: /etc/redhat-release: Is a directory
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-89-generic/build M=/home/user/rtl8188eus  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-89-generic'
cut: /etc/redhat-release: Is a directory
cut: /etc/redhat-release: Is a directory
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-89-generic'
cut: /etc/redhat-release: Is a directory
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.4.0-89-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 5.4.0-89-generic
```

The internet is working using the adapter but can't turn ON the monitor mode on it. While running `sudo airmon-ng`, "null" is shown under "PHY" section of the adapter which is probably due to unsuccessful driver installation.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Please help...

Comment: Welcome, what are the actual commands you are running?

Comment: Following `git clone` command, I ran `echo 'blacklist r8188eu'|sudo tee -a '/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf'` and `make && sudo make install`

Comment: I don't know where did you get that github link, but it's not the official one, and surely the commands you are running aren't correct ones to perform the install. [The official github is this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu), and there you have the steps to install.

Comment: Oh wait, I don't know if it's a difference between `rtl8188eus` and `rtl8188eu`.

Comment: Yeah, I think they are different. I don't quite know which one should I go for. I referred to this website: http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2

Comment: In the page you link you can read *"Probable Linux driver
r8188eu (OoK, vendor driver) +"*, you can give `rtl8188eu` a go.

Answer (score 0):

Have got the source of the module ? Here (`https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/blob/master/Makefile`), I don’t find a reference of the `redhat-release` file which on RedHat should be a plain file with the version of RedHat and perhaps other related informations (I haven’t it’s format, but it is not a directory).

Comment: Do I have to run these codes? How to use them?

Comment: You have a directory `/home/user/rtl8188eus` where you put the source of the driver. But I don’t know where (or how) you got them. Then it is difficult to help you. When searching such a driver, I have found one which seems to be done for Debian and alike distribution. Perhaps you should have look to https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Comment: "lwfinger/rtl8188eu" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170202/how-to-install-rtl8188eus-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04